# javascript function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

Why calling the JavaScript function , works fine in some places in the code and gives my the function is not defined in other place in the code in the same page !

js function:

```
function loadActivityInfo(id){
/// code goes here
   $("#location_details_div").fadeIn(1000,function(){
       getRating(id);
       getRateAverage(id);
       getActivityInfo(id);
       goToLocation(id);

  //scroll inimate to top
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#location_details_div").offset().top - 60
    }, 1000);
   });
}
```

call it here, works fine :

```
$(".img-describtion").live("click",function(){
    resetRating();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    location.hash= id;
    loadActivityInfo(id);
});
```

but here gives me the funcation is not defined :

```
$(".btnShowLocationInfo").live("click",function(){
        var id =$(this).attr("id").split(",")[1];
                alert(id);
                location.hash= id;
                loadActivityInfo(id);
    });
```

Comment: Where do you execute the code? In the body? In the head in an init function?

Answer (score 2):

You need wait that the compleat document is downloaded.

E.g. it is not possible to call a function inline if you include the function later. For callbacks that is no problem.

You can put your initial code to the onload event.

```
<body onload="doinit();">
```